# Alguem me ajuda a alterar a imagem pelo indice em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Eu estou tentando ir mudando a imagem conforme o valor da variavel num muda. Por exemplo, de 0 a 100 é uma imagem, de 101 a 200 é outra e assim sucessivamente.

Eu coloco qualquer numero de 0 a 100 e ele me retorna a imagem do indice 0, coloco qualquer numero de 101 a 200 e me retorna corretamente a imagem do indice 1, porem de 201 pra cima as imagem nao alteram e continua mostrando a do indice 1.

```
var num = 568
var fotos = ["./img/Emblem_Iron.png", "./img/Emblem_Bronze.png", "./img/Emblem_Silver.png", "./img/Emblem_Gold.png", "./img/Emblem_Platinum.png", "./img/Emblem_Diamond.png", "./img/Emblem_Master.png", "./img/Emblem_Grandmaster.png", "./img/Emblem_Challenger.png"];
function alterarImagem() {
    if (num <= 100) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = fotos[0];
    } else if (num >= 101 || num <= 200) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = fotos[1];
    } else if (num >= 201 || num <= 300) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = fotos[2];
    } else if (num >= 301 || num <= 400) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = fotos[3];
    } else if (num >= 401 || num <= 500) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = fotos[4];
    } else if (num >= 501 || num <= 600) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = fotos[5];
    } else if (num >= 601 || num <= 700) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = fotos[6];
    } else if (num >= 701 || num <= 800) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = fotos[7];
    } else {
        document.getElementById("img").src = fotos[8];
    }
}
```

no html está assim

```
<img id="img" src="./img/Emblem_Iron.png" class="elo">
button id="btn" class="play" onclick="alterarImagem(400)">test</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

O problema aí é estás a usar um `||` (OU) em vez de um `&&` (E).

Como 400 é maior que 101 logo a condição:

```
if (num >= 101 || num <= 200)
```

é sempre verdadeira.
Se mudares para

```
if (num >= 101 && num <= 200)
```

nesta e nas condições seguintes já deverá funcionar.

Comment: Funcionou! eu sou novo em javascript, nao sabia muito desses detalhes! MUITO OBRIGADO!

Answer (score 4):

Se você utiliza || (ou) como condição, logo, ele não vai confirmar as duas condições, porque uma delas já é satisfatória.

Por exemplo:

205 é maior que 100, então, não precisa que eu confirme se é menor que 200, pois:

*OU* é maior que 100, *OU* é menor que 200. Entendeu?

Troca os *||* por *&&*, que o seu problema resolve.

Abs!

Comment: Funcionou! eu sou novo em javascript, nao sabia muito desses detalhes! MUITO OBRIGADO!